# Trying to install GMAT

Tags: linux

I'm relatively new to the world of Linux on a Chromebook, so I probably won't know what you talking about unless you make it really clear.
For those who don't know, GMAT is a NASA software tool to model orbits, spacecraft, and celestial bodies. I am 99% there, but I get stuck on a screen that says to "enter a script file, q to quit, or an option". I would really like to create a launcher so I can open GMAT, but all the places I go just make it more confusing. Any thoughts?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAPYY.png)

Comment: GMAT depends on MATLAB (installed on same Workstation)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please include all the necessary information on your question, and avoid external links.